# How do I remove the background color of the appbar in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

I want to remove the white color of the top appbar and make it match with the map. How can I do that?
My CSS code:

```
.hello {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom:6px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-right-width: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  z-index: 100;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;

}
```

Comment: `background-color: transparent` should do it but what is the color of element behind it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by matching the color of the map - given the map has many colors? Do you want your list to be over the actual map?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that that map is actually behind the appbar.
Maybe you need to apply a negative margin-top to the map.